# Uploading a image to firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, jpeg, firebase-storage

I have been using the firebase guides to upload a user image to firebase storage but after I upload the user image nothing appears in the folder. How do I solve this problem to successfully upload my image to firebase storage is there anything i'm missing ?

> Size 0 bytes

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
         let image = UIImage(named: "ProfileImage")
       let data = Data()
         let starsRef = storageRef.child("ProfileImage.jpeg")
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "ProfileImage/jpeg"
        let uploadTask = starsRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
         guard let metadata = metadata else {
           return
         }

         let size = metadata.size

         starsRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
           guard let downloadURL = url else {

             return
           }
         }
       }
```

Comment: As a guess - this is the issue... `guard let data = image?.pngData() else { return }` is returning nil so the code silently fails. The error is because this `let image = UIImage(named: "ProfileImage")` because *ProfileImage* is not in your project bundle. To fix, drag an image like *myImage.png* into your bundle, change the code to match and you're good to go. Also, fix this `metadata.contentType = "ProfileImage/jpeg"` as that's *not* a content type. See the guide - try `"image/png"`

Comment: you mean like let riversRef = storageRef.child("myImage.png")

Comment: That's a reference to an image called myImage.png in storage which is unrelated to the issue. As I mentioned in my above comment, what is `ProfileImage` in this statement `let image = UIImage(named: "ProfileImage")`? Where is *ProfileImage*? Are you loading it from disk? Is it in memory? Was it dragged into your app bundle? Is it a .png? a .jpg? I am guessing the compiler doesn't know what that is, so the `image?.pngData()` ends up being nil and just returns before the rest of the code executes.

Comment: okay how do I drag myImage.png into my bundle and make it match @Jay

Comment: There are a variety of ways to add images to your project. You can drag and drop them into the project itself, you can load them from disk or even create them in memory. You should familiarize yourself with those options - SO has a search engine at the top where you can find other related questions and examples. If you decide to drag a .jpg to your project, then update this line of code with the name `let image = UIImage(named: "the image name goes here.jpg")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 6 steps on how to upload the image to Firebase Storage and retrieve the URL path for later usage.

1. Create an unique name using `UUID().uuidString`
2. Compress the image into `compressionQuality`
3. Sat the metaData as .jpeg
4. Add the data to Firebase Storage
5. If succeeded, retrieve the image URL
6. Convert the URL to `url?.absoluteString` and print it out using `print`

   ```
       //1. Create an unique name for your image
       let imageName = UUID().uuidString
       let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(imageName)

       //2. Compress quality
       if let uploadData = self.tempImageView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5){

           //3. Save image as .jpeg
           let metaDataForImage = StorageMetadata()
           metaDataForImage.contentType = "image/jpeg"

           //4. Add the data to Firebase Storage
           imageReference.putData(uploadData, metadata: metaDataForImage) { (meta, err) in
               if let err = err{
                   print(err.localizedDescription)
               }
               else{
                   //5. Retrieving the image URL
                   imageReference.downloadURL { (url, err) in
                       if let err = err{
                           print(err.localizedDescription)
                       }
                       else{
                           //6. Print the complete URL as string
                           let urlString = url?.absoluteString
                           print(urlString)
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: what exactly is tempImageView @Putte

Comment: @FredGreg tempImageView is the imageView which holds the image you just uploaded to the app.

Comment: @FredGreg Worked fine? :) and the UrlString i’m retrieving can be stored in the regular firebase database and retrieve the image just by calling like I did

Comment: What urlString Did you use send it to me @Putte

Comment: the image is no longer showing in the database why is the image data optional @Putte

Comment: @FredGreg Hm, no longer showing? They don’t auto remove images.  The URL string is the path from the image

Comment: Yeah The ProfileImageUrl Link Is Not Popping Up In Database @Putte

Comment: @FredGreg That's because you have to add it to the Database. - Firebase Storage is just a location where the image can stay online. So the `urlString` I'm printing in the very bottom is used to store in the Firebase/Firestore database.

Comment: @FredGreg So what you need to do is to add that `urlString` into your "ProfileImageUrl"

Comment: @FredGreg Google how to add data to Firestore

Answer (score 0):

Make that `let data` a `guard let data`, that way you won't have to force-unwrap when you need it to be non-optional. I'd say generally avoid force-unwrapping in general.

Comment: I tried that now the image won't appear at all @Uragawa

Comment: If you have the `guard let` on `image`, that means the UIImage initialiser is failing, most likely because it can't find an image with that name. Check your asset catalog.

Comment: I switched it check it out @Uragawa

Comment: @FredGreg This is explaining how to safely unwrap optionals, and while good info, it's not an answer as it doesn't address the question or the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `contentType` should be `image/jpeg`. I [googled some piece codes](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=YnteDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=StorageMetadata+contentType+jpeg&source=bl&ots=46nwitl1NS&sig=ACfU3U2Zlix72LLqstAjb1RyZ4U3g_VeyQ&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU1cbOn4_oAhXLc94KHRN_CsYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=StorageMetadata%20contentType%20jpeg&f=false), it shows the same concept.
2. About `contentType`, [more detail at this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).
3. If you upload an image with jpeg format, then you should upload `jpeg` binary. But `data = image.pngData()`, it seems to be the binary data of `png`.

---

```
// data is `png` binary
let data = image.pngData()
// imageData is `jpeg` binary 
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)
let uiImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!

 let starsRef = storageRef.child("ProfileImage.jpg")
let metadata = StorageMetadata()

// About contentType
// See it: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Content_type&redirect=no 
metadata.contentType = "ProfileImage/jpeg"

// data is `png` binary, but contentType is `jpeg` ? 
let uploadTask = starsRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
 guard let metadata = metadata else {
   return
 }
```

Comment: @FredGreg The code here *is* your code - however, the comments above each section describes the issue with that section of code.